# IDocumentQueryListener - appending to every query

Tags: ravendb

Is there a way to use IDocumentQueryListener to append a predicate to every query?

We logically delete everything, so I want to append "IsDeleted:false" to all my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,
Yes, you can cast it to IDocumentQuery and add it there.

Comment: I already tried to go down that route, but you need to be able to assign the result of an additional predicate to something. e.g. var whatDoIAssignThisTo = (queryCustomization as IDocumentQuery<Document>).WhereEquals("IsDeleted", "false");

Comment: The only way I can see of doing it is to reflectively grab theQueryText StringBuilder object and append my lucene predicate, which is obviously all kinds of wrong!